# Need to edit and delete using DAO

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem i'm having.
I have a ReminderDAO class with methods to delete, edit, insert etc and a Reminder class with a constructor and get and sets.

I then have a a view reminders where it just lists all the reminders out.
I want to be able to add an edit and delete to this view page.

To use the delete and edit functions in my ReminderDAO class, i need to pass a reminder object through the function and i'm not quite sure how to do this.

If anyone could help me that would be of great help, i'm new to this language so i apologise if it's not great code.

Thank you in advance!

**Reminder DAO**

```
class ReminderDAO extends DAO {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert($reminder) {
        if (!isset($reminder)) {
            throw new Exception("Reminder required");
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Reminders(member_id, title, details, reminder_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $params = array($reminder->getMember_id(), $reminder->getTitle(), $reminder->getDetails(), $reminder->getType());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not save Reminder: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve new reminder's id: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $id = $row[0];
        $reminder->setId($id);
    }

    public function delete($reminder) {
        if (!isset($reminder)) {
            throw new Exception("Reminder required");
        }
        $id = $reminder->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Reminder id required");
        }
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Reminders WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($reminder->getId());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete reminder: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function update($reminder) {
        if (!isset($reminder)) {
            throw new Exception("Reminder required");
        }
        $id = $reminder->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Reminder id required");
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE Reminders SET member_id = ?, title = ?, details = ?, reminder_type = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($reminder->getMember_id(), $reminder->getTitle(), $reminder->getDetails(), $reminder->getType());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not update Reminder: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function getReminder($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Reminders WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($id);
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve Reminder: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $reminder = null;
        if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $id = $row['id'];
            $member_id = $row['member_id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $details = $row['details'];
            $type = $row['reminder_type'];
            $reminder = new ReminderDAO($id, $member_id, $title, $details, $type);
        }
        return $reminder;
    }

    public function getReminders() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  Reminders";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve reminders: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $reminders = array();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        while ($row != null) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $member_id = $row['member_id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $details = $row['details'];
            $type = $row['reminder_type'];


            $reminder = new Reminder($id, $member_id, $title, $details,  $type);
            $reminders[$id] = $reminder;

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $reminders;
    }
}
?>
```

**Reminder Class**

```
<?php
class Reminder {
    private $id;
    private $member_id;
    private $title;
    private $details;
    private $reminder_type;


    public function __construct($i, $m_id, $title, $det, $type) {
        $this->id = $i;
        $this->member_id = $m_id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->details = $det;
        $this->reminder_type = $type;
    }
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function getMember_id() { return $this->member_id; }
    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
    public function getDetails() { return $this->details; }
    public function getType() { return $this->reminder_type; }


    public function setId($i) { $this->id = $i; }
    public function setMember_id($mID) { $this->member_id = $mID; }
    public function setTitle($t) { $this->title = $t; }
    public function setDetails($d) { $this->details = $d; }
    public function setType($type) { $this->reminder_type = $type; }


}
?>
```

**View Reminders**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/Member.php';
require_once 'includes/MemberDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/Reminder.php';
require_once 'includes/ReminderDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/session.php';
confirm_logged_in(); // needs to come before any html because it does a redirect
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require 'toolbar.php';
        $member = ($_SESSION['member']);

        $reminderDAO = new ReminderDAO();
        $reminders = $reminderDAO->getReminders();



        echo "<p>Hello " . $member->getFN() . "</p>";
        echo "<p>These are the current reminders:  </p>";


        foreach ($reminders as $rem) {
            echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $rem->getTitle() . "<br />";
            echo "<b>Details:</b> " . $rem->getDetails() . "<br />";
            echo "<b>Type: </b>" . $rem->getType() . "<br />";



           echo "</p>";

        }


        echo $display; ?>
        <a href="add_reminder_form.php">Add Reminder?</a>



    </body>
</html>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

**edit_reminder_form.php class**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'includes/session.php';
require_once 'includes/Member.php';
require_once 'includes/MemberDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/Reminder.php';
require_once 'includes/ReminderDAO.php';
require_once 'includes/session.php';
confirm_logged_in(); // needs to come before any html because it does a redirect
?>

<?php

 $reminderDAO = new ReminderDAO();
 $reminder = $reminderDAO->getReminder($_GET['id']);




?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit Reminder</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <h2>Edit Reminder</h2>
             <?php if (isset($_GET['errorMessage'])) echo "<p>".$_GET['errorMessage']."</p>"; ?>
               <form action="edit_reminder.php" method="POST">
                   Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php $reminder->getTitle(); ?>" /><br/>
                   Details: <input type="text" name="details" value="<?php $reminder->getDetails()?> " /><br/>

                   <select name="reminder_type" value="<?php $reminder->getType();?>">
                <option value="Choose">Please choose a reminder type!</option>
                <option value="Bill">Bill</option>
                <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
                <option value="Event">Event</option>
                <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="reminder" value="Edit Reminder" />
               </form>
            <br />
            <a href ="view_reminders.php"> Cancel </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <?php
    //5.Close connection
    if(isset($connection)) {
     mysql_close($connection);
    }
    ?>
</html>

<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the `ID` of the `reminder` to the next page where you edit/delete a reminder.

```
foreach ($reminders as $rem) {
        echo "<b>Title:</b> " . $rem->getTitle() . "<br />";
        echo "<b>Details:</b> " . $rem->getDetails() . "<br />";
        echo "<b>Type: </b>" . $rem->getType() . "<br />";

        echo "[<a href='edit.php?id=" . $rem->getID() . "'>Edit</a>] ";
        echo "[<a href='delete.php?id=" . $rem->getID() . "'>Delete</a>] ";

       echo "</p>";

    }
```

In `edit.php` you get the reminder object using the ID (e.g. `$_GET['id']`), load the data from the database using ReminderDAO and create a form populated with the reminder values. In that form, you should also put the reminder id, so when he submit the form to `Save changes`, you can identify the reminder that was edited.
After saving the changes, you can redirect him back to the list of reminders using `header` function.

Similar, in `delete.php` you can delete the reminder using the ID (e.g. `$_GET['id']`) and then redirect the user to the list of reminders.

Comment: thank you very much for that answer! however i am not really sure what you mean in the edit.php. would you be able to show me what i would write on the line with the $_GET['id']? if you have time of course. Thank you again.

Comment: You could do something like this to retrieve the reminder object with the id sent via GET: `$reminder_to_edit = $reminderDAO->getReminder($_GET['id']);`

Comment: and unfortunately, when i echo the $_GET['id'] on the next page and in the URL when i click edit all that comes up is "()" and no id is being passed through.

Comment: How does the URL look like? Does the id have a value? (e.g. `localhost/my_project/edit.php?id=3`)

Comment: Oh.. I updated the code to use `" . $rem->getID() . "` instead. Let me know if it worked

Comment: yes, that works great! thank you so much :)

so when i get to the edit page i should have a form? so that they can change it? and then use an update statement from the DAO?

Comment: Yes, you will have a form so they can edit the information. The next step (the same file or new file `edit_proccess.php`) would be saving the changes using the update statement from DAO

Comment: i'm still having a problem with the edit. i am trying to populate the  form, but am having trouble. i have edited my code to show you what i have.

Comment: The select tag doesn't have an attribute `value`. Instead, the selected option should have the attribute `selected`

Comment: no :( when i try to use the get['id'] on the getReminder function it doesn't work. it's very confusing.